# Не определено свойство "CSafeValidator.0

Tags: yii

Непонятная ошибка `Не определено свойство "CSafeValidator.0".`
Во отображении

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    //'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'dataProvider'=>$schools1Model->searchFullMonSchoolsForAdmin($id),

    'filter' => $schools1Model,
    'columns'=>array(   
            array('name' => 'area.ShortAreaName',       
                  'filter' =>  CHtml::activeDropDownList(
                           $schools1Model,
                           'ShortAreaName',
                            CHtml::listData(Areas::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('IsDeleted' => '0',), array('order' => 'AreaCode ASC')), 'AreaCode', 'ShortAreaName'),
                            array(
                                'empty'=>'',
                            )
                        ),
            ),

            array('name' => 'ShortSchoolName',   ), 
            //и другие поля

)
```

Ругается на строку `array('name' => 'ShortSchoolName',   ),` (когда ее убираешь, все нормально).
Контроллер:

```
$schools1Model=new Schools1('searchFullMonSchoolsForAdmin('.$id.')');
$schools1Model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values                
$this->render('index', array( 'schools1Model' => $schools1Model, 'id' => $id));
```

В модели `Schools1` в функции `searchFullMonSchoolsForAdmin($id)` строка есть `$criteria->compare('ShortSchoolName',$this->ShortSchoolName, true);`

```
public $ShortAreaName;

public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('SchoolCode, SchoolName, ShortSchoolName, Password, CountPeople11, CountPeople10, CountPeople9, SchoolKindFK, SchoolTypeFK, SchoolPropertyFK, AreaCodeFK, TownTypeFK, GovernmentCode, LawAddress, Address, Phones, Faxs, Mails, WWW, ChargeFIO, ChargePosition, EGEChargeFIO, GIAChargeFIO, UpdateDate, IsDeleted', 'required'),
            array('SchoolCode, CountPeople11, CountPeople10, CountPeople9, SchoolKindFK, SchoolTypeFK, SchoolPropertyFK, AreaCodeFK, TownTypeFK, GovernmentCode, IsDeleted', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('SchoolName, ShortSchoolName, Password, LawAddress, Address, Phones, Faxs, Mails, WWW, ChargeFIO, ChargePosition, EGEChargeFIO, GIAChargeFIO', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('SchoolID, SchoolCode, SchoolName, ShortSchoolName, Password, CountPeople11, CountPeople10, CountPeople9, SchoolKindFK, SchoolTypeFK, SchoolPropertyFK, AreaCodeFK, TownTypeFK, GovernmentCode, LawAddress, Address, Phones, Faxs, Mails, WWW, ChargeFIO, ChargePosition, EGEChargeFIO, GIAChargeFIO, UpdateDate, IsDeleted', 'safe', 
            'ShortAreaName', 'area.AreaCode', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
```

В чем может быть тут дело, что это за ошибка?

Comment: Покажите содержимое валидации модели, вы неправильно задали валидатор

Comment: Показала. ..........

Comment: У вас, кажется, последний валидатор имеет слишком много элементов. Я не уверен, что проблема именно в этом валидаторе, но она точно заключается в неверном задании валидатора Safe - Yii получает на вход не то, что ожидает, и пытается присвоить элемент ноль, как у массива, валидатору.

Comment: Да, проблема оказалась в последнем валидаторе :array('SchoolID, SchoolCode, SchoolName, ShortSchoolName, Password, CountPeople11, CountPeople10, CountPeople9, SchoolKindFK, SchoolTypeFK, SchoolPropertyFK, AreaCodeFK, TownTypeFK, GovernmentCode, LawAddress, Address, Phones, Faxs, Mails, WWW, ChargeFIO, ChargePosition, EGEChargeFIO, GIAChargeFIO, UpdateDate, IsDeleted', 'safe', 
            'ShortAreaName', 'area.AreaCode', 'on'=>'search'),
'ShortAreaName', 'area.AreaCode' нужно было поставить в  первый элемент массива, где перечислялись все поля, а у меня они были как отдельные элементы массива